# Run a program for fixed number of time

Tags: c

I am trying to write a code which can be run for limited number of time( like it happens in trial versions) say 5 times or 10 times.. after that the code will not run.
I had an approach but it modifies the source code. I don't want that. Moreover use of external files is prohibited.
This was my code with source code modification approach - U have to put the fseek value(here 38) counting the position if 5 in int x=5. (am not sure if am clear)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int x=5;
char c;
FILE *f;

if(x>0){
    f=fopen("FT.c","r+");
    fseek(f,38,SEEK_SET);
    fprintf(f,"%d",--x);
    fclose(f);
    printf("%d time left",x);

}else{
    printf("you cannot run more than 5 time");

}
return 0;

}
```

N.B.  I dont want to compile the source code again n again. I want the executable file to be made then that .exe file can be run for a limited amount of time

Comment: What's preventing someone from modifying the file manually?

Comment: So you have to think where to store the count.  A database?  A Registry key.  A call to an external licensing server?

Comment: Also your logic doesn't make any sense. You're never reading a value from the file __into__ x. The `else` condition will never be run.

Comment: This code is not of my use. i pasted it to make clear what i tried to do.

Comment: What you're asking for is [Digital Rights Management or DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management). Even the largest software companies can't make it work reliably for the fundamental reason that if I can run your code I can modify your code. All DRM is is a speed bump. Your idea of altering a number in the binary it is ***very*** easy to find and defeat. Friendly tip: don't waste your time on it. Instead, have a license and enforce it, or don't distribute your software (ie. provide it as a server). But do try it as an exercise.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this, but it's not a good idea.

What you're asking for is [Digital Rights Management or DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) and it doesn't work. Even the largest software companies can't make it work reliably for the fundamental reason that if I can run your code I can modify your code. All DRM is is a speed bump. Your idea of altering a number in the binary it is very easy to find and defeat. Friendly tip: don't waste your time on it. Instead, have a license and enforce it, or don't distribute your software (ie. provide it as a server).

---

But let's do it as an exercise.

Append a number to the end of the *compiled* executable. The executable reads that to determine the number of times it has remaining, and rewrites it with the new number of times.

There's any number of ways to put the number on the end. You can write it there with a hex editor. I used a small Perl program to write the 4 bytes.

```
# It's backwards because x86 machines are little-endian.
# And you're probably on an x86 machine.
$ perl -we 'open my $fh, ">>", shift; print $fh "\x03\x00\x00\x00";' executable
```

That means the program has to...

1. Open itself using `argv[0]`.
2. Seek 4 bytes from the end.
3. Read the last 4 bytes into a 4 byte integer.
4. Check that it's not 0.

We need to read/write a specific number of bytes, so I'll be using uint32_t to have a fixed size 4 byte integer.

```
// Open our own executable for reading.
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[0], "rb");
if( fp == NULL ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Can't open %s for %s: %s", argv[0], mode, strerror(errno) );
    exit(-1);
}

// Seek 4 bytes from the end.
if( fseek( fp, -4, SEEK_END ) != 0 ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Can't seek: %s", strerror(errno) );
    exit(-1);
}

// Read 4 bytes
uint32_t times = 0;
fread( &times, 4, 1, fp );

if( times == 0 ) {
    printf("Program expired. Please give me $money$.\n");
    exit(-1);
}
else {
    printf("You have %d tries remaining.\n", times);
}
```

Writing is very similar.

1. Open itself using `argv[0]`.
2. Seek 4 bytes from the end.
3. Write the new number of times remaining.

```
// Open our own executable for reading & writing.
// Can't use "a", that will always write to the end of the file.
// Can't use "w", that will erase the file.
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[0], "r+b");
if( fp == NULL ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Can't open %s for %s: %s", argv[0], mode, strerror(errno) );
    exit(-1);
}

// Seek 4 bytes from the end.
if( fseek( fp, -4, SEEK_END ) != 0 ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Can't seek: %s", strerror(errno) );
    exit(-1);
}

fwrite( &times, 4, 1, fp );
```

---

Again, this form of copy protection is barely a speed bump. Anyone who knows what a hex editor is can easily recognize it and break it. Anyone who doesn't can Google for instructions written by someone who does. This answer is only for an exercise.

Comment: thank you so much for the details. but i dont understand one thing, where to decrease the time for each time it is running?

Comment: when i tried to run this code, i got "You have 6646123 tries remaining.
Can't open C:\Users\ria\Downloads\limited.exe  error Permission denied" i could not get it. and i cant use the variable mode as it is saying not declaed in the block

Comment: and if possible could you explain this $ perl -we 'open my $fh, ">>", shift; print $fh "\x03\x00\x00\x00";' executable

Comment: @DebasmitaBhoumik Like I said, this is a bad idea. I don't want to hand you complete code that you could cut & paste in without understanding it, so I left a few basic parts out. You should look into [file permissions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm) for why you can't write to the file, and fool around with a [hex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor) to understand how you're altering the executable. You don't need the Perl, it was just one way to add the initial count to the executable; use a hex editor.